# docker compose merging yaml files fails with conflicting services

Tags: docker, merge, yaml

I want merge 2 docker compose and I get some errors:

common/compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  hello-world:
    image: hello-world
```

prod/compose.yaml

```
include:
  - ../common/compose.yaml
services:
  hello-world:
    environment:
      - name=value
```

Then I try to start the container with:

prod/compose.yaml: `docker compose up`

I get the error:
***Imported compose file [common/compose.yaml] defines conflicting service hello-world***

If I remove the service section it works.
Why is the service not merged? This should work in docker compose > 2.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/14-include/) for the `include` keyword, it seems it wasn't intended for this use:

"Compose displays a warning if resource names conflict and doesn't try to merge them."

You may need to instead resort to running `docker compose -f common/compose.yaml -f prod/compose.yaml` as per the [example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/#example) provided in the official documentation.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your answer.
I have to remove the include attribute, then it will work